# php operator precedence

Tags: php, math

I'm having trouble understanding how php calculates standard math functions. In a specific example I have this calculation:

225 + 154 * 256 + 138 * 256 * 256 + 81 * 256 * 256 * 256
(thats correct, no brackets)

which when executed with php produces this number:
1,368,038,113

Now when I look at this logically and work through the sum from left to right, this number doesn't even come close. using a cheap simple calculator, it gives up trying to calculate it before the last two multiplications of 256 because the number gets too big.

How is it possible to end up with such a relatively small number from a calculation with 6 multiplications by 256?

A breakdown of how php actually would work out this answer would be great.

p.s. i read through this page: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php2p8.html which still didn't help me with the above.

Comment: Operator precedence is the same as for formal mathematics: multiple/divide have precdnence over add/subtract

Comment: If you want to force add and subtract to go first, you can wrap them in brackets: `5 * 2 + 3` is not the same as `5 * (2 + 3)`

Comment: I get the same exact result if I use my cheap calculator equivalent (Spotlight in Mac OS X).

Comment: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=225+%2B+154+*+256+%2B+138+*+256+*+256+%2B+81+*+256+*+256+*+256`

Comment: There's a manual page devoted to that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
225 + 154 * 256 + 138 * 256 * 256 + 81 * 256 * 256 * 256
```

=>

```
225 
+ 
154 * 256 = 39,424
+ 
138 * 256 * 256 = 9,043,968
+ 
81 * 256 * 256 * 256 = 1,358,954,496
```

=>

```
225 + 39,424 + 9,043,968 + 1,358,954,496
```

=>

```
225 
+ 
39,424 
+ 
9,043,968 
+ 
1,358,954,496
```

=>

```
1,368,038,113
```

**EDIT**

Why do I think you're doing:

```
225 + 154 * 256 + 138 * 256 * 256 + 81 * 256 * 256 * 256
```

=>

```
225 + 154 = 379
* 
256 = 97,024
+ 
138 = 97,162
* 
256 = 24,873,472
* 
256 = 6,367,608,832
+ 
81 = 6,367,608,913
* 
256 = 1,630,107,881,728
* 
256 = 417,307,617,722,368
* 
256 = 106,830,750,136,926,208
```

Comment: Hi Mark, can you add some explanation and braces? It is painful to read as of now.

Answer (score 7):

The result is correct. PHP will perform the multiplication first and then the addition. It looks like this:

```
$res = 225 + (154 * 256) + (138 * 256 * 256) + (81 * 256 * 256 * 256)
$res = 225 + 39424       + 9043968           + 1358954496
$res = 1368038113
```

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted answer, because it is shorter and outlines the error right away.

Answer (score 2):

PHP follows the rules of mathematics:

BODMAS (Brackets, Orders, Division, Multiplication, Add, Subtract)

So in your case it would evaluate like this:

```
225 + 154 * 256 + 138 * 256 * 256 + 81 * 256 * 256 * 256
225 + 39424 + 9043968 + 1358954496
1368038113
```

If you want to do it in a different order, use brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Basic order of operations from math is: multiplication/division then addition/subtraction.

Using a super simple calculator, it does operations one at a time.  So a simple calculator  would probably treat your input like this messy string:

`(((((((((225 + 154) * 256) + 138) * 256) * 256) + 81) * 256) * 256) * 256)`.

Answer (score 1):

as usual multiplying has precedence over adding. I have counted the equation and its correct so i dont see what is your problem...?

"this number doesnt even come close" <== thats right, because its exact:

```
225 + 154 * 256 + 138 * 256 * 256 + 81 * 256 * 256 * 256
=225 + 39424 + 9 043 968 +1 358 954 496
=1 368 038 113
```

What number did you expect? how did you count it?