# PHP 2 same calculation but different outcome, why?

Tags: php

My apologies for this question but I am brand new with PHP.

So I tried out 2 same calculations in PHP but I get different outcome.
Here are the samples.

```
      <?php
    $var = 4;

    $var = $var * 23;
    $var = $var - 46;
    $var = $var + 86;
    $var = $var / 2;
    $var++;


    print $var;

   ?>
```

Outcome is 67

```
      <?php

    $var = 4;

    $var = ($var * 23) - 46 + 86 / 2;
    $var++;

    print $var;


   
   ?>
```

outcome is 90

So basically they were correct until when its on the line where it says / 2.
On that line it changes the outcome. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952299/php-operator-precedence helps?

Comment: dunno about your country but in mine we were learning the [order of arithmetic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) in the elementary school

Comment: The answer in the marked dupe lacks explanation and requires observation from the reader to understand what's going around. God, it is already paining my eyes. I expected better from Mark Baker as I am a fan of his excel plugin made for PHP.

Comment: @Kenny It is actually the latter one but there are some cons.

Answer (score 1):

Both expressions are *not same* although they look same to the naked eye.

```
$var = ($var * 23) - 46 + 86 / 2;
```

is the same as

```
$var = ($var * 23) - 46 + (86 / 2);
```

because division takes precedence over addition in computers. If you wish to overrule this, use braces `()`, like  `$var = ($var * 23 - 46 + 86) / 2;`.

There are several other examples you may want to learn like below:

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

echo 86 + 4 / 2, "\n"; // gives 88

echo 86 * 4 / 2, "\n"; // same as (86 * 4) / 2, gives 172

echo 86 % 3 / 4, "\n"; // same as (86 % 3) / 4, gives 0.5

echo 86 % 3 * 4 / 5,"\n"; // same as ((86 % 3) * 4) / 5, gives 1.6

echo 86 * 3 % 4 / 5; // same as ((86 * 3) % 4) / 5, gives 0.4
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onlinephp.io/c/a30ac)

Between `%`, `*` and `/`, it is all about order from left to right. Whoever comes first, will have their precedence over the other.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change

```
$var = ($var * 23) - 46 + 86 / 2;
```

to

```
$var = (($var * 23) - 46 + 86) / 2;
```

In the first example (which you did), 86 is first divided by 2. In the next, the whole expression is divided by 2.

I suggest you review this manual.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think the both calculations are equal? A division has higher precedence than an addition, `+ 86 / 2` is not evaluated from left to right